# how to detect a string of records in a input.file with no costant NF?

Tags: awk, gnuplot

I've a input_file.txt in this way:

```
1
0.421934 0.421622 384000
0.419202 0.418349 384000
0.422398 0.422148 384000
0.422691 0.422789 384000 D
0.427295 0.426805 384000
0.424004 0.423169 384000
0.428237 0.428279 384000
2
0.422842 0.422462 576000
0.420401 0.419927 576000
0.42179 0.421462 576000
0.424359 0.424637 576000 F
0.425756 0.425569 576000
0.421996 0.421274 576000
0.428395 0.428422 576000
```

I'd like to have an output_file.txt as:

```
1 0.422691 0.422789 384000 D
2 0.424359 0.424637 576000 F
```

(I put the letters D and F only to indicate easily the two lines that I want)

How can I do this using awk?

Thank you

Comment: @JamesBrown the OPs posted data contains a red herring: `(I put the letters D and F only to indicate easily the two lines that I want)`. ila - if those 2 letters don't exist in your input, what is your actual criteria for selecting the lines to output?

Comment: @EdMorton Ah, didn't get that one. Why D and F? How confusing is that? Maybe the fourth after every `NF==1`. Well, we'll wait for OP.

Comment: @JamesBrown I can't imagine why the OP would mess with their sample input like that, why they'd choose those letters in particular, or what the real selection criteria is. Talk about "unclear"!

Comment: I choose always the forth line after NF=1

Answer (score 1):

if you want to choose the fourth line after `NF=1` (and print it together with the line corresponding to `NF==1`), an option could be:

```
gawk 'NF==1{f=4;g=$1;next;} !(--f){print g,$0;}' input_file.txt
```

Comment: If you set `f=5` you can loose that `next`.

Answer (score 1):

Mark the record to be printed to a variable (`nr` below) and compare it to `NR`:

```
$ awk 'NF==1{nr=NR+4} NR==nr' file
0.422691 0.422789 384000 D
0.424359 0.424637 576000 F
```